# Add default data to Axios request

Tags: axios

I am working on a project with React and a Rails API.

In each of my Axios requests, I want to pass a variable to my API.

Can I configure Axios to tell it to add a variable in the data when I try to POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH…?

Example:

```
axios.post('url', { data: 'some_data' }).then(...)
```

→ API should receive:

```
data_of_request = { data: 'some_data', added_data_from_config_axios: 'some_variable' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a better answer.
I just used a built-in function of axios:

```
const added_data_axios = {
  'add_data': '..some_data..'
};

const api = axios.create({
  transformRequest: [(data) => {
    return {...added_data_axios, ...data};
  }, ...axios.defaults.transformRequest],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own function like this.

```
const sendPost = (url, data = {}, headers = {}) => {
  var body = {...data, added_data_from_config_axios: 'some_variable' };
  return axios.post(url, body, { headers });
}
```

And then, you use this function instead of `axios`

```
sendPost(url, { data: 'some_data' }).then(res => {
  ...
});
```